# How could I determine what areas of the Milky Way will be visible?

Tags: milky-way, photography, positional-astronomy, constellations

There is a new moon on Saturday, and the forecast in my area of Winnipeg, Manitoba, Canada calls for clear skies on that night.

I would like to take a widefield astrophotograph.

I have no idea what areas of the milky way will be visible, and where they will be located.

What are some steps I could take to determine this?

Are there different dense (photogenic) portions of the milkyway visible at different times of the year?

Are there certain constellations associated with the dense portions of the milky way that I should be looking for?

I would like to further develop my knowledge of astronomy, for the purpose of widefield milkyway shots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to use Stellarium? 
You can insert the date of the observation and see how the sky will look like from your location.
 There is also setting to make the Milky Way be seen more intense.

Comment: Cheers mate :) Happy photon hunting!